# GNU Parallel More Frequently Check Nodelist

Tags: gnu-parallel

I am using GNU Parallel for managing submissions across a remote cluster and local machines. As stated in the man page, -sshloginfile is only rechecked after a job completes. However, all of my jobs take 8h+ to complete. Is there anyway to check the sshloginfile more often?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not. But why would you need it?

What would it accomplish to have it checked more often?

Comment: Hi Ole, thanks for the awesome software. Suppose you have queued allocations on a cluster that are periodically granted. You could have that script edit the nodelist, and then your parallel instance running on some local machine would use those remote hosts until timeout.

Comment: Is this a feature that might ever be supported?

Comment: @AndrewSaydjari I still do not understand what it would do, how it would work and what problem it solves. It is probably best to discuss this on the mailinglist: parallel@gnu.org